# MySQL query for checking query is not working in JDBC

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have a problem with JDBC about a query. `checkdata` is the query and it is not working.

```java
String checkData= "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE pdesc="+pdesc+" AND bid="+bid+" AND quantity>0";
ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery(checkData);
if(isStockEmpty(rs)){
       String purchaseData="INSERT INTO purchases(puid, cid, bid, pdesc, pwhen) VALUES ("+(puidCount+1)+","+cid+","+bid+",'"+pdesc+"','"+pwhen+"')";
       insertQueryPurchases(statement, purchaseData);
}
```

It works in the MySQL though.

```
select *
from stock
where pdesc='FoodHorse brand olive oil 1L' and bid=1 and quantity>0;
```

And here is the table

```
CREATE TABLE stock
( 
    bid             int             NOT NULL,
    pdesc           varchar(500)    NOT NULL,
    quantity        int             NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (bid, pdesc)
);
```

Comment: first of all, get rid of string concatenetion against injection vulnerability by checking PreparedStatements out.

Comment: Thank you, I am searching for these terms. We didn't learn them in the class.

Comment: pdesc is not quoted change **pdesc="+pdesc+"** to **pdesc='"+pdesc+"'** . This argument is a string and must be quoted. You also did it in the MySQL sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Barbaros Ozhan mention, Using PreparedStatement is recommended approach to avoid parameter issues in JDBC. And to know exact issue please share your error stack.

Here reference code for PreparedStatement for your case.

```
String checkdata = "SELECT * FROM jpa_jbd.stock where pdesc=? and bid=? and quantity > ?";
   PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SELECT_SQL);
   ps.setString(1, pdesc);
   ps.setInt(2, bid);
   ps.setInt(3, quantity);
                
   ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                
   if(isStockEmpty(rs)) {
        String purchaseData = "INSERT INTO purchases(puid, cid, bid, pdesc, pwhen) VLAUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        insertQueryPurchases(psforinserQuery, purchaseData);
    }
```

Comment: It worked thank you very much. I am sorry I don't know what the error stack is but the solution solved the problem. Thank you again.